# Is there a utility to deeply compare objects in Google Closure Library?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

I hope there is such tool in this big library. But I can't find it.

Offtopic: is there a nice feature list for GCL in the net?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you don't really care for performance, you can do a deep value comparison with a little JSON magic.

```
function isEqual(objA, objB) {
    return goog.json.serialize(objA) === goog.json.serialize(objB);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work:
> goog.json.serialize({'a':2, 'b':2})
"{"a":2,"b":2}"
> goog.json.serialize({'b':2, 'a':2})
"{"b":2,"a":2}"

Comment: @Ken: your comment is very serious, the developer is responsible for controlling the properties order!

Comment: @Dan Are you disagreeing? quoting json.org - "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs". The developer should never assume property order.

Comment: @Jan, you're missing return inside isEqual function body in the answer. Otherwise, your function always returns undefined.